# Using JS library installed via npm in Typescript Angular 2 project

Tags: typescript, npm, webpack, angular, cal-heatmap

I don't manage to use [cal-heatmap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cal-heatmap) in my Angular2 project written in TypeScript. Any help on how to get this going would be appreciated.

I am using webpack ([webpack.config.js](http://pastebin.com/pFQQK7zx)) to bundle the application. Here is the [ts.config](http://pastebin.com/6Q3DQeNm). I installed cal-heatmap with npm and type definitions with tsd. In my application's TypeScript code I would do like:

```
import * as calheatmap from 'cal-heatmap';
```

However, when I open the application in a browser `calheatmap` remains undefined and nothing is imported. The library is based on d3 and d3 itself works. Using the same package installation procedure the following just works inside my application:

```
    import * as d3 from 'd3';
```

I suspect cal-heatmap does not work because its [JS code](https://github.com/wa0x6e/cal-heatmap/blob/master/src/cal-heatmap.js#L1) (from NPM) or the [ts.d](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/cal-heatmap/cal-heatmap.d.ts) are not compatible but I don't know how to remedy this.

Any hints would are appreciated, thanks!

Comment: try this: `/// <reference path="./pathToYourLIbTypings/cal-heatmap.d.ts" />`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. This doesn't fix it and IIRC the reference notation is not required for recent versions of Typescript anymore.

Comment: http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook compare the "Ambient Internal Modules" with "Ambient External Modules"

Comment: I'll check that link, thanks. Hopefully this part of the documentation is still up to date.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into something similar.
https://github.com/wa0x6e/cal-heatmap/issues/192

I was using systemjs though. Funny thing is the CalHeatMap object loaded perfectly in the browser, but didn't loaded in the component.

I imported d3js and c3js like that and they loaded perfectly.
One thing I noticed is that, the other libraries keep the functionalities inside an object(i.e d3 in d3js); whereas in cal-heatmap they're returning a function(CalHeatMap is actually a function if you look inside the [source-code](https://github.com/wa0x6e/cal-heatmap/blob/master/cal-heatmap.js#L11)).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I got this to work. Never mind the typings for the cal-heatmap module. They don't export anything so there are not useful in this case. No need to install.

You can then do:

```
import * as CalHeatMap from 'cal-heatmap';
...
new CalHeatMap().init({});
```

Before, I was trying to call init directly on CalHeatMap without instantiating, kind of n00b.

Answer (score 0):

If you're bundling cal-heatmap with Webpack4, because of the global var in cal-heatmap.js, I also needed to use Webpack ProvidePlugin like this:

```
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        CalHeatMap: "cal-heatmap"
    })
```

Otherwise I'd see this error at runtime:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: CalHeatMap is not defined
 at Module../src/app/js/myapp.js
```