# Import d3js into Ionic2 typescript project

Tags: d3.js, angular, ionic2

I cannot wrap my head around how i can import d3js library in a ionic typescript projet. I installed the library using :

```
npm install d3 --save-dev
```

The library is in node_modules/d3. In my page modules, I try to import using every possible path, for example :

```
import * as d3 from 'd3/d3'
import * as d3 from '../../../node_modules/d3/d3'
```

I always get the error:

```
Error TS2307: Cannot find module 'd3/d3'.
or 
Error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../../node_modules/d3/d3'`.
```

Any hint to help me ?

**Angular version 2.0.0-rc.1**

**Ionic : 2.0.0-beta.9**

Thanks

Comment: Do you have `d3.d.ts` file in your solution? Like this one https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/d3/d3.d.ts

Comment: This is how you do Module resolution https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html

Comment: I have installed the definition using : typings install d3 --global --save

Comment: Take a look [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/use-of-third-party-js-libary-with-typings-in-ionic2-project/41047/5) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34746304/using-js-library-installed-via-npm-in-typescript-angular-2-project)

Comment: using import * as d3 from 'd3' results in the same error : Error TS2307: Cannot find module 'd3'

Comment: @gpasse did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @inspired Hi not really, but I can use d3js. You can check that post https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/d3js-import-typescript/56027

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a workaround the issue.

What I did :

Link d3js in the index.html (at the end of the file, bellow app.bundle.js):

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

Then in my page.ts (before @Component) :

```
declare var d3: any;
```

And then you can use it like :

```
d3.select("#graph svg").remove();
```

So I am not using import (you should delete the import if you want to use this solution)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
npm install @types/d3 --save
```

I just tried it and it works. More info [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/resources/third-party-libs/).